# Politely phrase "how do you do"

Tags: phrase-usage

I found in dictionary that phrase `How do you do` is equivalent to phrase `Nice to meet you`.
But I never heard it in any movie or tv serial.
Is that right or not

Comment: What is "right or not"? The phrases, or the fact that they may not be in movies/on TV?

Comment: Please see Matt's excellent answer on [our existing question about "How do you do?"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/4533/230).  People don't really say it anymore.