# Proper words to utter when shaking hands with others?

Tags: sentence-usage, politeness

I want to know what might be proper ways to express our regards to others when shaking hands with others in occasions such as church?

I found that when shaking hands with others, often I do not get any reply from others if I say "how are you doing" or "how is it going". So I am wondering why and what are the proper words to say in this context?

Comment: For those who voted this question to close: Without leaving any comment at all, your voting to close is opinion-based and too broad. Ironic enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"How are you doing?" and "How is it going?" are correct things to ask when shaking hands (especially with people you have already met, like your fellow church-goers).

Many people treat these questions as perfunctory greetings (like "Hello") instead of as genuine questions.  Thus, it is OK for people to not respond to them; they probably do not even realize you asked a question.  (I sometimes get strange looks when I treat "How are you doing" as a question worth a short but thoughtful answer.)

"Howdy" is a less formal version of "How are you doing" that has become a synonym of "Hello", and so is rarely treated as a genuine question:
[ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/do-you-really-answer-how-do-you-do-with-how-do-you-do](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4526/do-you-really-answer-how-do-you-do-with-how-do-you-do)

Comment: Thank you so much :) You just hit the point! Now I know the problem is not at my words. Yep, next time I should try "howdy", that sounds cute

Comment: I would suggest *not* saying 'Howdy' unless you are trying to be funny or are in a part of the country that does use "Howdy" as a normal greeting (In which case you'd have heard people using it by now).  I'd suggest "[It's] Good to see you." to which you may or may not get a "[Good to see] You too."

Comment: @Comeseeconquer- If someone says, "How are you doing" to me, I typically *will* respond with a "Great, how 'bout you" or a "Fine, thanks, and you?" regardless of whether I'm actually great/fine or not.  I assume people are just trying to be personable/polite and are not really interested in my problems.

Comment: I like a big "Howdy!" but I live in Texas, so it's not that uncommon. Also, "It's nice to see you (again)." works well because it doesn't really need a response like "how are you?".